# I want to modify the drop down menus for Marinelli (a Drupal theme)

Tags: 7, routes, theming

I have the Marinelli menu setup in a website I am internal testing.
I want to modify the drop down menu (I know it uses jQuery), but I have no idea what to do to show the drop down all nested.

In other words, instead of having this in the Marinelli theme

- MENU1
- submenu
- underMenu
- undermenu
- submenu
- undermenu

I want to have the menu like the [corolla theme](http://demo.kiwi-themes.com/?theme=corolla)

- MENU1
- submenu
- submenu

and when I hover a submenu:

- SUBMENU
- undermenu
- undermenu

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The marinelli_menu.js on the marinelli theme folder is controlling the JavaScript.

[image: marinelli_menu javascript]

The primary-links.css file is handling the theming.

[image: menu css]

Armed with this knowledge you can use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to easily [tweak the CSS and find out how it looks](http://getfirebug.com/css) without having to save the file. And with Firebug's [command line](http://getfirebug.com/commandline) and debugging you can explore how those JavaScript functions behave and what's the best way to modify them if necessary.

If you don't know JavaScript or CSS then you have bigger issues.